# angellist api access - sign up for an api

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

Lately I been trying to access angel.co api. But what I got is "We are not accepting any new sign ups for the API." message. Does anybody know if this a temporary measure, or any other details about this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If anyone interested - guys from angellist told me via email that currently they aren't planning to open up applications to the API.